# Java Regex to match Dockerfile arg values

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract [Dockerfile ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) values which are usually of these forms:

```
$foo, expected output: foo
${foo}, expected output: foo
```

I want to capture the string after `$`. I'm trying this regex right now but it doesn't seem to working for second test case with curly braces:

```java
private static String extract(String input) {
    Pattern argPattern = Pattern.compile("^\\$([^{}]+)$");
    Matcher matcher = argPattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return (matcher.group(1));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Could anyone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: What kind of chars can there be in between `{` and `}`? Only letters, digits, `_` or more?

Comment: I think docker allows letters, digits and `_`

Comment: Ok, then `[^{}]` in my solution below can be replaced with another `\w`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\$(?:\{([^{}]+)\}|(\w+))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Oil3ng/1). **Details**:

- `\$` - a `$` char
- `(?:\{([^{}]+)\}|(\w+))` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\{([^{}]+)\}` - `{`, then Group 1 capturing one or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}`
  - `|` - or
  - `(\w+)` - Group 2: any one or more letters, digits or underscores.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/re6x9R):

```java
String s = "$foo1 expected output: foo ${foo2}, expected output: foo2";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$(?:\\{([^{}]+)\\}|(\\w+))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
    } else { 
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); 
    }
}
```

Output: `foo1` and `foo2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!